# How to display predicted data for a lead window size superior to 1 in Encog time series

Tags: java, time-series, prediction, encog

I am new to encog and try to fit the examples to my needs. I am using the [SunSpotTimeseries](https://github.com/encog/encog-java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/encog/examples/guide/timeseries/SunSpotTimeseries.java) in Java (). 
By default, the lagWindowSize is 3 and the leadWindowSize is 1. I do not worry about the lagWindowSize at the moment. 
I just want to increase the leadWindowSize to 2 or more. For a value of 1, I understand that you get the predicted value through the 'predicted' variable (easy...).
My problem is I do not really see how to get the other predicted values if the leadWindowSize is superior to 1. I tried to see what was in the 'output' variable without that much success.
Thanks in advance